# Problem with installing the Openni_kinect

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i try to install the openni_kinect, i face a few problems...

when i type: rosinstall ~/openni_kinect PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall'

i get this as the answer: E: rosinstall operating on /home/user/openni_kinect from specifications in rosinstall files  PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE, http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall
ahhhh error opening file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/drivers/PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE'
Usage: rosinstall PATH [ ...] [URI]...

rosinstall: error: None

what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10247/problem-with-installing-the-openni_kinect/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you should replace PATH_TO_EXISTING_ROS_TREE by the actual path to your ROS installation.

---

Originally posted by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) with karma: 202 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-14**:
thanks....was able to install...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

or maybe you can just use `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-openni-kinect`. It works for Ubuntu and Maverick.

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1